# "Almost harmonic" series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a real sequence with $a_n > 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

For which, if any, such sequences $(a_n)$ do we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{(1+a_n)}} < \infty$?

(The motivation for this question is the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{x}} < \infty$ if and only if $x > 1$.)

Comment: Do you mean
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\color{red}{n}^{(1+a_n)}}\;?$$

Comment: You are right - sorry for my typo!

Comment: also i think for series you want n=1 not n=0 or else you aredividing by 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence or not is a case-by-case matter, since by the [Cauchy's condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we have that our series converges if
$$ a_n = 2\frac{\log\log(n)}{\log n} $$
while diverges if
$$ a_n = \frac{\log\log n}{\log n}.$$